# What are these tiny, round, black bugs on my bed and couch?

Tags: dogs, bug-identification, ticks

I moved into a house way out in the country in Kansas.  Sitting in my bed yesterday I saw the tiniest, tiniest round speck.  Perfectly round, black and somewhat shiny. I had to zoom in with my phone camera to see that they were alive. They move slowly.  After realizing it was a bug I started to find more and more. They are on the bed and couch.  Both are places the dogs have been laying.  Could they be coming in on the dogs?

I thought maybe bed bugs but they don't really look right.  I need help,  my 2 year old son sleeps with me and I am worried that we are getting bit. They snag pretty easy and just leave blood.

[image]

Comment: Can you count the legs? Theres a plethora of similar questions by the way. Googling images on "tiny round shiny black bugs couch" gives me a ton of the same questions on this stack exchange. It seems unlikely they are ticks if there's so many though. Most probably a variation on bedbugs or something similar. Likely nasty, but not dangerous

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/a/E2Ba5U3 these seem to similar and a vet thought they were tick from the dog. I would lean to that direction, as they show blood after being killed. Normally you do not want to get buit by ticks at all, as they might carry diseases like lyme. They might prefer the dog, but best to sleep somewhere else and get your full skin checked for them by someone who knows how to deal with ticks. They prefer to be under skin like arm pits or private areas. If they are ticks, the amount is alarming.

Comment: Without higher definition photos I would lean strongly in the direction of ticks - I can't see any clear definition of head and thorax/abdomen,  and the legs are all in the "same" location, which looks tick-like.

Answer (score 2):

Those are certainly some kind of tick, with the three most likely kinds being the [*American Dog Tick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermacentor_variabilis) (*dermacentor variabilis*), the [*Lone Star Tick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblyomma_americanum) (amblyomma americanum), or the [*Deer Tick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ixodes_scapularis) (*ixodes scapularis*). These three ticks are native to your area.  Additionally, all of these ticks has similar appearances when fully engorged as they are in your picture, making it harder to tell specifically which kind it is from the provided picture (and probably in general for most people).  They absolutely could be falling off of your dog.

I strongly recommend you do the following:

- If your dogs are outside in wooded or grassy areas, you should avoid these areas to the best of your ability, or at least minimize the time spent in them.  If you can, cut down tall/overgrow areas to reduce the chances for ticks to latch on your dogs (and yourself).
- You should probably bathe the dogs with a flea and tick shampoo.  There are plenty out there on the market to choose from.
- Treat your dogs with some sort of flea and tick treatment, such as K9 Advantix (again, plenty of other options to choose from).
- Check yourself and your family members for ticks.  Ticks are extremely small, with deer ticks being some of the smallest - especially in their larva stage.  You'll want someone to give you a really good look over, especially through your hair.

[image: tick sizes]

It is possible to contract [Lyme Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease) from deer ticks, which could make this a more severe situation.  I would check your dogs over for symptoms of this.  One of the most common symptoms of Lyme Disease is a red bulls-eye like ring formed around the bite of where the tick was.

Comment: It should be necessary to point out that ticks themselves are not actually insects, but rather known to belong to a class of eight-legged arthropods known as 'arachnids'; therefore ticks are usually a part of the same class as mites and all spider types. However a relatively small portion of the unsuspecting might inadvertently mistaken ticks for other insects like bed bugs and cockroaches, partly due to their unique shape and body material.